# If $\sqrt{n}(\widehat{\theta}_{n}-\theta) \to N(0, \frac{1}{I_1(\theta)})$, what does $\sqrt{n}(\widehat{\theta}_{kn}-\theta)$ converge to?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that

$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\widehat{\theta}_{n}-\theta\right) \overset{D}\to N\left(0, \frac{1}{I_1(\theta)}\right)
$$

From this, is it true that:

$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\widehat{\theta}_{kn}-\theta\right) \overset{D}\to N\left(0, \frac{1}{I_1(\theta)}\right)
$$

where $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

In other words, my sequence is further ahead in the second equation.

Comment: Multiply and divide $\sqrt{k}$ to see what you will get.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I see, so basically we get a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}N\left(0, \frac{1}{I_1(\theta)}\right)$ distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $k$ is fixed. Follow the advice of [Zhanxiong](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/192408/zhanxiong)
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\widehat{\theta}_{kn}-\theta\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \sqrt{nk}\left(\widehat{\theta}_{kn}-\theta\right)\overset{D}\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} N\left(0, \frac{1}{I_1(\theta)}\right)=N\left(0, \frac{1}{kI_1(\theta)}\right)$$

And if suddenly $k=k(n)\to\infty$, the limiting distribution will be degenerate at zero by Slutsky Theorem.

Comment: @Did Thank you for correcting this crazy mistake! Was in a hurry, and did not check the text.